# Is it possible to addTotals in agrid to only certain columns?

Tags: atk4

When I use addTotals() in a Grid, it sums every column with number fields, How to show only the ones I want?

Answer (score 0):

you can override `formatTotalsRow()` and clear up what's not needed from `$this->current_row[]`