# addTotals to CRUD Grid crashes edit

Tags: atk4, php

Pretty simple issue. I know that that CRUD uses Grid so I did:

```
        $finances = $grant->ref('Finances');
        $crud=$tabs->addTab('Finances')->add('CRUD', array('allow_add'=>false, 'allow_del'=>false));
        $crud->setModel($finances);
        $crud->grid->addTotals(array('requested', 'committed', 'spent'));
```

This adds the total row but caused the popup displayed by the edit button to have nothing inside - just a blank white popup. Anyway to get totals without "crashing" the CRUD Grid?

Comment: In case anyone else wonders what Grid?... http://agiletoolkit.org/codepad/gui/grid

Comment: If you use addTotals() with no arguments do the totals show up?  I know it would include columns you don't desire to sum.  Also, are you getting any errors of any kind?  Similar posts on SO: [ATK4 - addTotals() results in 0.00 for totals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784194/atk4-addtotals-results-in-0-00-for-totals) and [Is it possible to addTotals in agrid to only certain columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170210/is-it-possible-to-addtotals-in-agrid-to-only-certain-columns)

Comment: @ficuscr no errors and no totals without specifying columns. The totals row gives me "-" if I don't specify columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/atk4/atk4/issues/102